# Percentage of nervous energy used by human eyes

Tags: human-eye, energy

I am reading a book 'How to stop worrying and start living' by Dale Carnegie. I stumbled across this statement below and I couldn't find any research article to backing this claim. Does anyone know if this claim is reasonable or not?[image: The claim is that eyes use up a quarter of the total nervous energy] Following is the claim:

> The reason the eyes are so important in relieving nervous tension is that they burn one fourth of all nervous energies consumed by the body.

Comment: "Nervous energy" might seem not to refer to refer to calories as much as fidgeting and muscular tension. Could you clarify the disjunct between the question title and the image text. We discourage text images, as those using a text reader for reasons of accessibility are less likely to be able to read it, if you can use the quote function and type the text in, that would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for editing in the quoted text, but as I indicated, the phrase "nervous energies" is idiomatic, it doesn't refer to Joules or calories, it refers to muscular tension and restless fidgeting. Could you make the title agree with the body of the question. We also require that you show your prior research, once you've worked-out what question you're asking that is.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about this topic while doing my research that is why I thought I could ask in this forum

Comment: This seems very...non-rigourous. To be honest, I've heard what I can only refer to as quacks speak in a similar manner.

Comment: But the question is very unclear, the title being different from the body of the question - please begin by editing so that it's making sense.

Comment: Could you do it, I don't know how to frame it better

Comment: There is no metric known to me that fits the description "nervous energies". It's the sort of unchallengeable rhetoric that self-help gurus come up with that gives the impression that it's in some way scientific, but the meaning is more intuitive than quantifiable by science. If you can find a metric for "nervous energy" then I'd be surprised if it had a sound methodological underpinning. Don't let that stop you trying though.